# Writing an equation with integer coefficients

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

An algebraic number is any complex number that is a root of a non-zero polynomial in one variable with rational coefficients. for example write an equation which $\sqrt2 +1$ is  one of its root ,with integer coefficients .
$$x=\sqrt 2+1 \to x-1=\sqrt 2\\(x-1=\sqrt 2)^2\to \\x^2+1-2x=2\\x^2-2x-1=0$$ 
other example :write an eq. with integer coefficients which $x=\sqrt2 +\sqrt3$ is a root.
$$x=\sqrt2 +\sqrt3 \\x^2=2+3+2\sqrt6\\(x^2-5)=(2\sqrt6)\\(x^2-5)^2=(2\sqrt6)^2\\x^4+25-10x^2=24\\x^4-10x^2-1=0$$
or$$x-\sqrt2=\sqrt3\\x^2+2-2\sqrt2x=3\\x^2-1=2\sqrt2x\\(x^2-1)^2=(2\sqrt2x)^2\\x^4+1-2x^2=8x^2\\x^4-6x^2+1=0$$ 
Now: my question is about :an equation which one's root is $x=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt 5$ and coefficients are integer .

How many equation we can write for it ? w.r.t "coefficients are integer"
How can write this equation easily ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A polynomial with rational coefficients will have the exact same solutions as the polynomial where every coefficient is multiplied by a non-zero constant.  If you let the non-zero constant but the least common multiple of the denominators, this polynomial will have all integer coefficients.  Hence rational vs. integer coefficients isn't relevant and the process is the same for either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is :$$x=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt 5\\x-\sqrt5=\sqrt2+\sqrt3\\(x-9\sqrt5=\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2\\x^2+5-2\sqrt5x=2+3+2\sqrt6\\x^2-2\sqrt5x=2\sqrt6\\(x^2-2\sqrt5x=2\sqrt6)^2\\x^4+20x^2-4\sqrt5x^3=24\\(x^4+20x^2-24)^2=(4\sqrt5x^3)^2$$ Is there an easier way  ?

Comment: Don't know that it's easier (or that it counts as an answer) but if using a CAS one convenient way is using polynomial resultants, for example [`resultant[ resultant[ resultant[ x-u-v-w, u^2-2, u ], v^2-3, v], w^2-5, w]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+resultant%5B+resultant%5B+x-u-v-w,+u%5E2-2,+u+%5D,+v%5E2-3,+v%5D,+w%5E2-5,+w%5D) $\;=x^8 - 40 x^6 + 352 x^4 - 960 x^2 + 576\,$ which is the same polynomial as yours.